# Importing JPGs for Data Studio Reports

Tags: looker-studio

My agency partner would like to import different JPGs into DS reports unique to each of their advertisers. Does anyone know if you we are able to import JPGs for individual advertisers?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add images through url links in a table. If you are using different row-level security for users then you could give them access to just their logo link and set the table up so you can't see the headers, cell borders, etc.

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7570489?hl=en